# How does a computer shutdown really work

Tags: computer-architecture

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but i'm asking anyway.

How does a computer shutdown really work?

I want to know the electronics (or physics) behind it. Like, how does a system signal make the device disconnect?

I am interested only in the last step of the process - when it is disconnected from the power - when the CPU stops receiving current.

My non-researched idea is that it actually never shuts down completely, as long as it is connected to power source.

(And the next question would be how does it really start up :D )

Comment: One word: software. A shutdown sequence is just a program that you execute. It does a lot of things, among these talk to devices to power themselves off.

Comment: really, your question is a bit too broad, because it shows you have a very superficial understanding of what a computer is (and still make claims about what shutdown means and what not), and if I wanted to write an answer, I'd start by writing a book about computer architecture. Anyways, physics really has nothing to do with it; a shutdown is still something on the level of abstraction of normal software operation of a computer, so looking at the physical side has zero benefit.

Comment: 99.99% of the equipment it is simple: you remove the power. The only thing which requires special action on a shut-down is the flushing of the file buffers & disk cache.

Comment: This is operating system dependent.  You should ask this on a site relevant to the OS you have.  It may store system status or simply flush file buffers before power removal.

Comment: I am interested only in the last step of the process - when it is disconnected from the power - when the CPU stops receiving current.
@Oldfart well, how do you write a program which "removes" the power? Or better, what does it really mean when a program removes the power?

Comment: The software sets a bit somewhere which then directly or indirectly causes an electronic circuit to behave like a power switch which is opened. The power button at the front of your PC 'closes' that switch again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993150/i-wonder-how-does-a-computer-inrernally-shut-down-when-we-click-on-shut-down-opt/40002262#40002262

Comment: Look up GPIO pins, and then imagine a GPIO pin connected to the power button.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the when the operating system has closed down properly, it says to the motherboard approximately the same thing as pushing the front panel button long - the motherboard turns off the ATX power supply, the main part of it. Then everything that uses main supplies won't get power any more, i.e. PU, memory, storage. The motherboard still gets standby power from power supply, and that is why pushing the power button, or getting a wake-on-lan packet can trigger the motherboard to turn the main supplies back on.

Comment: The bundle of wires from the ATX power supply to the motherboard contains one (green) wire that the motherboard can use to put the power supply into standby.

Comment: `the motherboard turns off the ATX power supply` This I don't understand how it works. How does it turn it off? By sending an electrical signal? Idk

Comment: Yes, like Simon B said, the motherboard uses the green wire to turn the power supply on and off. Connecting the green wire to ground will turn the power supply on, and disconnecting the green wire from ground will turn the power off.

Comment: @jack: do you remember how a RELAY works? imagine three circuits: power supply with two outputs, one has a RELAY on it, and that output is "normal power" to power everything (processor, memory, disks, ...). The other output (without a relay on it) is the "standby power" that is always connected to the motherboard, and also it is connected to the "power button". When you press the button, relay clicks, everything gets power. Your press it again, or motherboard sends a signal just-like-pressing-button,relay clicks, power is lost. And yes, motherboard CAN turn it self on as well: Wake-On-Lan(...)

Comment: @jack(...part2)In modern CPU power supplies there are no relays though, it's been replaced with thyristors, transistors, or integrated circuits, but the overall idea of operation is the same. And regarding the "(...) it actually never shuts down completely, as long as it is connected to power source." observation - it is correct. Any device plugged into the wall socket, unless it has a real RELAY that physically cuts the connection, is always somewhat powered as long as it is connected to the wall. It doesn't mean that 100% of the device is powered up. Many parts of it can be off until needed.

Comment: parts of the atx supply remain on so long as there is power and the switch is on. and this is detecting the "green" wire being shorted or not to a ground indicating power on.  this also keeps parts of your motherboard on while the "computer" is "off", wake on lan and other items.  If you look at the atx pinout you may see that there are some standby rails and the other rails that are switched.  software (think: windows) can tell logic on the motherboard to turn off the computer and that will then tell the atx supply to power off those power rails.

Comment: the power button on the motherboard is monitored by logic using the standby power and that in turn can tell the atx supply to turn power back on to those rails which then lights up other logic which does a power on sequence to bring things up. processor is released, bios/bootloader code happens, eventually operating system and so on.

Comment: this is very pc specific, a raspberry pi computer, off is off, you pulled the plug, and this has evolved over time older pcs off was off you hit the switch on the power supply